# split domain routing email

Tags: email, e-commerce, email-client

I am having e-commerce website through deco network  which have one fulfillment ( main domain ) but multiple affiliate stores . Each store is separate domain . When someone orders or any email communication through the store website they are receiving through my fulfillment email domain . The hosting provider doesn’t have option for multiple sender email for affiliate store and they include one email for the account . Can I use any service to route the email from the content and have assigned to domain related to the stores ?